Misunderstanding yunit in pstricks, or a bug, or extreme imprecision?
Feeding latex with
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
{1:
\begin{pspicture}(-.1,-1)(.1,5)
  \psline(0,0)(0,5)
\end{pspicture}}
{$10^{-4}$: \psset{yunit=.0001}%
\begin{pspicture}(-.1,-10000)(.1,50000)
  \psline(0,0)(0,50000)
\end{pspicture}}
{$10^{-5}$: \psset{yunit=.00001}%
\begin{pspicture}(-.1,-100000)(.1,500000)
  \psline(0,0)(0,500000)
\end{pspicture}}
{$10^{-6}$: \psset{yunit=.000001}%
\begin{pspicture}(-.1,-1000000)(.1,5000000)
  \psline(0,0)(0,5000000)
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}

then applying dvips to the resulting DVI file and opening the resulting Postscript file in gv should show, in my understanding, four vertical 5-cm-long line segments whose lowest point is 1 cm above the baseline. However, we get three line segments only, and they vary both in length and in the lowest point:

Is LaTeX with PSTricks really so imprecise, or is there a bug (e.g., a silent overflow/underflow) hiding anywhere? The log and console don't warn us.

tex uses fixed point arithmetic for lengths (that is integer arithmetic with scaled points) so you have about 5dp at most \dimen0=0.00001pt \showthe\dimen0 shows 0.2pt  and \dimen0=0.000001pt \showthe\dimen0 shows 0pt

@DavidCarlisle What is “dp”? Decimal point? Why have you written pt? I thought that the default unit of measure in pstricks is cm. Further, can pstricks be instructed to calculate more precisely (say, delegate the calculations to Postscript or to a floating-point library)?

"dp" meant decimal places there, sorry. for pstricks calculations are a mixture of tex and postscript arithmetic but at some point everything has to be a tex length to make sizes of boxes. whether you enter a length using cm or pt it is always stored as an integer multiple of sp (scaled points) and tex will always show the value in pt. I haven't traced exactly what is happening in your example but it's not at all surprising. you are using values that are small enough that you only have rounding error and no actual data value.

@DavidCarlisle I see. As the MWE above doesn't store numerical values in \dimen, my hope is that (for such a mature package as pstricks) the intermediate calculations to determine the box height (if everything is computed in scaling points, then, e.g., 0.00001 cm ⋅ 500000 ⋅ (7227/254 ⋅ 65536 sp/cm) or a mathematically associative and commutative rearranging thereof) could be given to someone else.

you are specifying the overall size of the box \begin{pspicture}(-.1,-100000)(.1,500000) by dangerously scaled tex calculations before postscript is used at all.

@DavidCarlisle I understand that the box size has to be computed before PostScript. From my viewpoint and in scientific notation, the two coordinates are simply (-1E-1, -1E+5) and (10E-1, 5E+5), where the unit is 1E-5 cm. Nothing dangerous for folks used to the usual floating-point arithmetics (say, IEEE 754). I was hoping (perhaps, overoptimistically) that the capabilities of the floating-point packages such as fp, fltpoint, and similar would have been used by pstricks meanwhile or that pstricks would do the job itself.

@DavidCarlisle Anyhow, is at least the contents of the bounding boxes drawn correctly for itself (although the box height and width might be extremely imprecise)? Or does TeX perform any calculations for the internal stuff before the figures are handed over to Postscript?

A value without a unit is by default in "cm". All calculations are done by the very limited possibilities of TeX. The internal calculations are done on pt level which leeds to great rounding errors if you have very small units. In such a case use always values scaled by 10^6 for example and change only the labels inside the coordionates. Or run lualatex and make all calulcation with \directlua...

TeX uses fixed point arithmetic and \psset{yunit=.000001}% gets saved  as an internal dimen register, \psyunit=0.000001cm which is equivalent to setting it to 0pt. The end result is that the final pspicture has height 0pt (and the heights of all of them are essentially arbitrary just depending on rounding error)
\tracingall\psset{yunit=.0001}\tracingnone

shows
\psyunit=\dimen166
...
{into \dimen166=0.00304pt}

so yunit is already at the limit of reasonable tex values,
your final setting
\tracingall\psset{yunit=.000001}\tracingnone

shows
{into \dimen166=0.0pt}

so the yunit is set to 0pt.

@AlMa1r try for yourself: `$ tex '\dimen0=0.000001cm\showthe\dimen0'
This is TeX, Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=tex)

0.0pt.
<*> \dimen0=0.000001cm\showthe\dimen0`


that is you are right that the value is interpreted as cm not pt but it makes no difference as it's 0 anyway. (I didn't check but it probably always stores first as pt then multiplies by a factor to get the right unit, but if that first assignment is 0 then the unit makes no difference @AlMa1r

@AlMa1r I edited to say 0.000001cm is 0 (rather than 0.000001pt as originally)

Do all calculations on PS-Level and let the TeX box (pspicture) in the TeX-friendly unit:
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\def\myLine(#1,#2)(#3,#4){%
  \psline(#1,#2)(!#3 #4 yunit mul)}

\begin{document}
{1:
    \begin{pspicture}(-.1,-1)(.1,5)
        \psline(0,0)(0,5)
\end{pspicture}}
{$10^{-4}$: \pstVerb{/yunit 0.0001 def}%
    \begin{pspicture}(-.1,-1)(.1,5)
        \myLine(0,0)(0,50000)
\end{pspicture}}
{$10^{-5}$: \pstVerb{/yunit 0.00001 def}%
    \begin{pspicture}(-.1,-1)(.1,5)
        \myLine(0,0)(0,500000)
\end{pspicture}}
{$10^{-6}$: \pstVerb{/yunit 0.000001 def}%
    \begin{pspicture}(-.1,-1)(.1,5)
        \myLine(0,0)(0,5000000)
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}


